# Word is adding an undeletable tab to the beginning of my bulleted lists?

Tags: microsoft-word

[image: misaligned bulleted lists]

So I'm having this weird issue in Microsoft Word where it's automatically adding a tab to the beginning of my bulleted lists (as in the picture above), after the bullet, and I can't delete or change it in any way.

Any thoughts on how to remove this?

Thanks.

Comment: See also Word MVP Shauna Kelly's page on managing bullets. http://shaunakelly.com/word/bullets/controlbullets20072010.html It is a bit more work, but bullets set up that way will behave predictably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click in the gap between the bullet and the text, and choose 'Adjust List Indents' from the menu

[image]

Adjust down the Text Indent property to say 1.3

[image]

---

This is what 5cm looks like

[image]

This is what 1cm looks like

[image]